# Fastest query to separate half of the table columns as part of DB normalization process

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012. I have a huge table (30Gb) and a pretty basic PC for this amount of data. I have a column (let's name it COL1) in this table, for which there is just one unique value per plenty of columns. I want to start with moving this duplicated data into separate table, where only unique values will be stored. Now the question is how to do that in a fastest way. Selecting count of distinct values for each column grouping by COL1 took me about 5 hours, now I know which columns need to be moved away from the table, but don't want to wait another 6-8 hours to do that. I have a non-clustered index on COL1 and a primary key on record id, please let me know if your solution will work better with some other indexes created.

Table has 50 million rows and about 100 columns. about 40 of columns contain time series data for many companies and about 60 contain descriptive data for each company, which is repeated. COL1 is the unique id of the company. As a result I would like to separate time series data from company description data, so that company description will be in a separate table and will have 1 line per company. There are about 22 thousand unique company ids in the dataset. Most of the company description columns are varchar.

I can't find a way to just take TOP 1 element for each COL1 value. I guess other options will take longer time to execute.

Examples of queries that I can think of:

```
select distinct tbl.COL1, tbl.add1, tbl.add2, other columns with duplicates...
into newtable
from tbl

select COL1, min(add1), min(add2), min of other columns with duplicates...
into newtable
from tbl
group by COL1
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does a column have "one unique value per plenty of columns"?

Comment: What are you actually trying to save in the destination table?  Do you just a single column containing the distinct values of COL1?

Comment: So you now have the list of unique values? How many are there?

Comment: Please show some sample data, your table structure, and maybe some example code of what you are trying to do (even if it doesn't work or is not efficient).  This isn't very clear.

Comment: So, you want to normalize your data by moving repeating groups from one table into another, thus establishing a one to many relationship. Is it just the `COL1` column that is part of the repeating group? What is the schema of the table?

Comment: Please read the edited question. I tried to clarify everything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a clustered index on Col1 - if you havent got a clusterd index, your table is a heap and every query will involve a table scan. Create a covering index on the rows you want to return. A select DISTINCT (excluding col1) should produce the results you want. Insert into a table with a clustered index on your prefered sort order only.

Assuming your data is non varing you can then loop WHILE and insert where you take values between N*1000 and (N+1)*1000 -1

The add any further indexes which are helpful for returning your data

Comment: Thanks for reply. Before creating a clustered index on COL1 I need to drop PK on id, which is unique per each row, right? I can't have 2 clustered indexes as far as I know. Won't creating a covering index on all the 60 columns and then running a query with distinct take more time than just running the query with distinct?

Comment: I didn't quite get how to match DISTINCT (excluding col1) with COL1 values. Could you please show some sample code?

Comment: A primary key ensures that each row has a designated column with a unique value. A clustered index determins the order in which rows are stored. If you create a clustered index where there are duplicate values, SQL will create a "uniquifying" and hidden column in the back ground to ensure referential integrity to each row.

Comment: When you create an index, there is automatically a reference to the unique row in the table incorporated in the index- no way it could work otherwise.

Comment: Also indexes on text columns are limited in length in a trade off between disk space and seek performance. However if a row can be looked up through a covering index, there will not actually be a read of the underlying table (all the info is contained in the covering index and the SQL design guys are smart enough to have figuered this out. Only reading an index is quite quick. So it all hangs together. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is quite often true that the primary key column is also used as the clustered index. The primary reason is that an auto incrementing ordered value which has no other meaning than a row designator is a very good choice for a clustered index in terms of insert performance